# Receiving a file from a remote client

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, tcp, ftp

I have an asynchronous socket server that up until now has just receive simple requests with relatively small payloads.  I need to add the ability to receive files along with the request, but am not sure of the best way to do it.  To complicate matters, some connecting clients are C#, others are VB6 so the mechanism must be amenable to support a diverse client set.

- does .NET have a native mechanism to accomplish this?
- can I have my clients just turn the file into a byte array and pass that into their existing TCP stream, to be rebuilt at the server end?
- should I just let my server behave like an FTP server?

Comment: what options do u have? use aspx? wcf? tcp-ip client/server?

Comment: No WCF, it's just a very basic TCP socket server.

Answer (score 1):

> can I have my clients just turn the file into a byte array and pass
>   that into their existing TCP stream, to be rebuilt at the server end?

Yes.

Comment: I'm being told from the VB6 dev that the way a VB6 Winsock control works that writing huge payloads to it does not work well.  This sounds very suspect to me, but I know 0 about VB6 sockets.